# Importing numerical data into Blender's fluids simulation

Tags: python

I am an engineer that typically deals with explosive, fire, and compressible flow (supersonic) simulations. I have my own code that can calculate a realistic 3D fluid simulation for some of these extreme environments, but I want to see what I can do for fun in Blender to make these simulations look "nicer".

I found this question from a while ago that is almost exactly what I am trying to do:

https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18319

However, this was written a long time ago and a few of the links are no longer available. Any help would be great!